# Cant save image locally IOS8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

i have this code working on IOS7, its check if an image exist in device and if not, it download locally.

Now on IOS8 doesnt save nothing, could someone help me?

```
//folder where save
     NSString *ImagesPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

 // check if image exist
 NSString* foofile = [ImagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:nombreImagenLocal];
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];

 // check if image exist locally
 if (!fileExists){
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rutaCompletaLogo]];

 //if not, i save it
 if (data) {

     // url where is saved
     NSString *cachedImagePath = [ImagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:nombreImagenLocal];

     if ([data writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES]) {

 NSLog(@"Downloaded file saved to: %@", cachedImagePath);

 }// end
```

Comment: Use `writeToFile:options:error:` instead, and give it an NSError pointer. Then inspect the NSError to see what's wrong.

Comment: write error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x7f8170f37710 {NSFilePath=/Users/BEhost/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66E03424-9959-473C-9912-BEAD2BE9C8A4/data/Containers/Data/Application/79C7F75A-7A3C-4C26-88CE-3FC7B3DD12D2/Documents/, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f817315c590 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

Answer (score 0):

The path to 'Documents' folder has changed from iOS8. Check the [Apple tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)

Please, make sure you don't use hardcoded values. Use the methods provided by the API:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```

OR (as stated in the previous link)

`// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}`

Hope this helps!